# Not sure if serial connection is working

Tags: raspbian, serial, noobs

I have been trying to get this working for a couple of days now, and nothing I've read seems to fix it.

I am working on trying to communicate with the pi via a serial connection. My current setup is a B+ connected via USB-serial to the computer's USB via another USB to serial.  In case that's not clear, it is:

Pi USB--> <--converter--> <--Serial cable--> <--converter--> <--PC USB

I am using hyperterminal on the PC, and Raspian installed from NOOBS on the pi.

I have gotten things on the pi sorted to the point where it looks like it's sending the data without a hitch. I don't know if it actually is or not though, as hyperterminal isn't registering it. Nothing I send from hyperterminal seems to be getting to the pi either.

Can you see anything fundementally wrong with the setup I'm using?

Apologies if I have left out any important info, please feel free to ask for clarification.

Comment: Have you swapped TX and RX in the cable?  i.e. Pi TX should go to PC RX.

Comment: Erm... I don't think so...

Comment: Unless one ends TX is connected to the other ends RX nothing will happen.